# How to turn google sheet data into json

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-conversion

[image]I am currently trying to have a script that I can use in order to turn google sheet data into json that can include neighboring AND nested objects. Currently what I have is a script that can allow for the sheet data to turn into json that allows for nesting objects BUT it does not allow the ability to end one object and start a new one so there cannot be any neighboring objects and instead there's one parent object with children objects in it which is not what I'm after. I'm hoping that I'm just missing something in the current script in order to be able to end and start new objects so I will add the script below, thank you for any contributions to this question!

```
function formJSON() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var currentObject = {};
  var output = currentObject;                    
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][1]) {
      currentObject[data[i][0]] = data[i][1];
    }
    else {
      var newObject = {};
      currentObject[data[i][0]] = newObject;
      currentObject = newObject;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(output));
}
```

EDIT: Here I will provide the current result vs the result I'm after. The first result is from the sheet I have added as an image.

**Current Result:**

```
{
  "": {
    "asset": {
      "button": {
        "viewPDF": "View PDF",
        "viewSurvey": "View Survey",
        "viewPPT": "View PPT",
        "viewLink": "View Link",
        "rejoinMeeting": "Rejoing Meeting",
        "labels": {
          "associatedWith": "Associated Content",
          "attendees": "Attendees in this session",
          "filesAndDocs": "Files and Documents",
          "location": "Location",
          "messages": {
            "errorRetrieving": "There was an error retrieving the session details",
            "noAttendees": "Nobody is watching this session currently",
            "browser": {
              "messages": {
                "notSupported": "Your browser is not supported",
                "update": "Please update"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Desired Result:**

```
"asset": {
    "buttons": {
      "viewPDF": "View PDF",
      "viewSurvey": "View Web Page",
      "viewPPT": "View Presentation",
      "viewLink": "View Link",
      "rejoinMeeting": "Rejoin Meeting"
    },
    "labels": {
      "associatedWith": "Associated Content",
      "attendees": "Attendees in this Session",
      "filesAndDocs": "Files and Documents",
      "location": "Location",
      "notStarted": "This session hasn't started yet.",
      "playlist": "Session Playlist",
      "premiumSponsors": "Premium Sponsors",
    },
    "messages": {
      "errorRetrieving": "There was an error retrieving the session details.",
      "noAttendees": "Nobody is watching this session currently",
      "pointsForDocument": "viewing a document",
      "pointsForRatingAsset": "rating this asset",
      "pointsForVideo": "watching a video",
      "problemSaving": "There was a problem saving your rating. Please try again."
    }
  },
  "browser": {
    "messages": {
      "notSupported": "Your Browser Is Not Supported",
      "update": "Please download the most up-to date version of one of the following and try again"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample structure of the desired resulting JSON object?

Comment: Yes, I'll make the edit

Comment: I've updated it now

Comment: I am having a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to figure this out for days lol

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following:

```js
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var currentObject = {};
  var title ='';
  var newObject = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][1]) {
      newObject[data[i][0]] = data[i][1];
    }
    else {
      if(data[i][0] !="" && data[i][0] !=" "){
        if(title != ""){
          currentObject[title] = newObject;
        }
        title = data[i][0];
        newObject = {};
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(currentObject));
```

While this is not a full solution, I think that it should point you into the right direciton.

- The idea is that you should have some variable (in this case `title`) which is defined / overwriten in the `else` statement and which is the key to which nested objects will be assigned during the next `if` conditions
- Once the `else` condition is entered again, `title` is overwritten wiht the next nested object key.

Comment: So with this, how would the actual google sheet change compared to the image I've added?

Comment: If you just leave asset away (one level of nesting less) the code would work as you need.